# One to many relationship is putting relationship explicitly on child

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have the following:

```
class Project
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<URL> URLs {get;set;}
}

class URL
{
    ...
    public virtual Project Project {get;set;}
}
```

The database created adds `ProjectID` to the `URLs` database table...

How do I force entity to create the relationship table for me to remove that dependency on `URL` **without having to declare a new entity** called `ProjectURL` like so:

```
public class ProjectURL
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectURLID { get; set; }

    public URL URL { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
}
```

---

**What I currently have**:

**Projects**

```
ProjectID |
---------------------
64        |
```

**URLs**

```
URLID     | ProjectID |
---------------------
13        | 64
```

---

**What I want to have:**

**Projects**

```
ProjectID |
---------------------
64        |
```

**URLs**

```
URLID   | 
---------------------
13      |
```

**Project_URLs**

```
URLID   | ProjectID
---------------------
13      | 64
```

Comment: If you create relationship table it will be more like many to many relationship. If you are sure, you want 1:n relationship, why would you want to remove dependency?

Comment: I don't ever want a URL to link to more than 1 Project. but I also want to re-use URL type as a generic database table. Almost as if it were a class inheritance thing.

Comment: Sounds like you want 1:1 relationship where url is required principal(?).

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure the mapping for your URL entity so that it is splitted into two tables. One table will be the URL, the other will also contain the additional properties (like the foregin key to Project). Take a look at the [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696571(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

Your mapping configuration will look like:

```
class URLMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<URL>
{
    public URLMap()
    {
        Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new {p.ID, p.Project});
            m.ToTable("Project_URLs");
        });
        Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.ID,
                // all other properties separated by ,
            });
            m.ToTable("URLs");
        });
        HasKey(p => p.ID);
    }
}
```

Be aware of defining the same primary key for both tables (in the above example I assumed an `ID` property).

**edit:** In cas you don't know what to do with the mapping configuration class.
You have to add an instance of this class to the override of `DbContext.OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new URLMap());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here... I'm going to give this a try... for now in my live application, I have actually created the entity as I said in my OP... This looks cooler as I don't really want to keep having to create these separate entities.